# Accessing an exported components data() in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm just playing around with some component instance rendering within a Vue application and I was wondering, when pushing components to an array - how do we then access the data() from that given instance of the component?

So say I have something like this in App.vue (the "Grandfather" of all of my components). I have managed to push instances of both the CodeBlock and QuoteBlock components to the pageBlocks array (i.e., my front end app appends the component where I want it to be). Here is a snippet of my App.vue file:

```
components: {
    CodeBlock,
    QuoteBlock
  },
  data () {
    return {
      pageBlocks: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPageBlock (componentNomen) {
      this.pageBlocks.push({ componentName: componentNomen })
    },
    saveDraftPage () {
      for (let pageBlock of this.pageBlocks) {
        console.log(pageBlock.data)
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is an example of my CodeBlock data (the Quote block is "modelled" almost like for like except for a few variable name changes to distinguish it inside the component):

```
export default {
  name: 'CodeBlock',
  props: [ 'type' ],
  computed: {},
  data () {
    return {
      debug: true,
      codeBlock: null,
      codeBlockRows: [{
        'id': 1,
        'text': '$ click to edit this code block'
      }],
    }
  },
}
```

I've stripped out most of this component to keep things simple.

So, my question is, if the pageBlocks array in App.vue contains instances of the above exported component...how do I access the data within?

In my naiavity I thought it would be as simple as something like this:

```
for (let pageBlock of this.pageBlocks) {
  console.log(pageBlock.data);
}
```

But, alas, no luck yet...any tips?

Comment: I think for handling data between components It's good to use Vuex

Comment: Just so that I understand you correctly. You are pushing actual component instances into an array of another (parent) component? That's a pattern you really never want to follow. Components handle data in their `data` attribute, not other components.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann Hi Phillip - yes, it’s a dynamic rich text editor and I want to be able to add as many different block types as I like, in any order I want. I would argue that the way I have set it up is the most elegant so far.

Comment: Why don't you just let your data drive your rendering, use objects that determine the type of the component in your data as an array, loop over that array in your rendering using dynamic components with an `:is`-binding to each individual type of the object and bind the rest of the object's data via normal prop bindings to the dynamic component. Sounds much cleaner and you wont need to access data of children programmatically, which is a thing they were never designed for in the first place.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann That's kind of what I'm doing: `<component v-for="(pageBlock, index) in pageBlocks" v-bind:is="pageBlock.componentName" v-bind:key="index" v-bind:id="'pageBlockId' + index"></component>`.

Comment: Well then you can't access the data because the content of your `this.pageBlocks` doesn't contain instances of your component. It only contains plain objects including a single property, the `componentName` (looking at how you implemented `saveDraftPage`) - vue doesn't swap those out for actual components just because you use them in a render-loop.

Comment: Aaaaahhh, hmmm...ok so I should be passing data via this as well. I think I have a potential plan.

Comment: Yes, but make sure you are passing that data from your parent to each child via prop bindings and that you only manipulate the data of your `this.pageBlocks` or the data in the child component directly. Do **not** try to access their data attribute from the parent ;). Besides that things look fine.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? The approach you are taking so far is very anti-pattern as others have suggested too. If you explain what you want to achieve in detail, may be we end up with better solution

Comment: @Prashant User can add any number of different block types to their “post” - and they must be ordered as they have added them. To save the posts I wanted to loop over the array of postBlocks and send to be saved. For me, it’s not anti-pattern as it works incredibly well up to a point.